# What is the difference in capl between . and ::?

Tags: capl

I know it is a basic question but I didn't find anywhere an explication and I want to understand why sometimes the code are written using . or sometimes use ::.

For example:

Msg1::Signal

Msg1.Signal

When I read the code from my experienced colleagues I see these difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to explain, but in my experience it varies a bit depending on what type of object you are dealing with. Generally, I would say it has to do with scope. I'll try to explain with 2 examples.

**Example 1**:

Your dbc defines 2 messages (Msg1 and Msg2) which contain a signal named "Signal1". In CAPL, the "::" operator can be used to resolve the ambiguity of "Signal1".

This will not compile:

```
void foo() {
     $Signal1 = 1; //notice the "$" in front
}

on signal Signal1 {
    //do something
}
```

But this will:

```
void foo() {
     $Msg1::Signal1 = 1; //notice the "$" in front
}
on signal Msg1::Signal1 {
    //do something
}
```

So if you are accessing a message via its dbc definition, the "::" is used to resolve ambiguity. The signal is sort of treated a static member of the message and using the "$" operator will set/get the signal value on the bus via the IL (assuming the message is being broadcast).

**Example 2:**

The "." operator comes into play if you create a local message variable. In that case, you must use "." to access the signal (or other message properties), like this:

```
void bar() {
    message Msg1 msg;
    msg.Signal1 = 1; //notice there is no "$" symbol in front
    output(msg); 
}
```

In this case, the message seems to be treated more like a local (stack) variable.
Example 2 does not use the IL and we must use the *output* function to send the message.

This might not be a definitive answer, but I hope it helps.